# twitter bootstrap thumbnails number of elements per row

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to determine the number of elements rendered per row using jquery (or anything else) when using twitter bootstrap's thumbnails.

Comment: Explain better what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There could be an easier way to do this, but here's what I came up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ejynp/

The variable `thumbnailcount` contains the number.

Comment: I'm confused.  How would I use this to get the number of thumbnails in a row?  It seems like it counts all the thumbnails, not the ones that were rendered in one row.  Although, I guess I could try and get the x,y coordinate for each thumbnail and compare to extrapolate how many per row.